# iOS7 and jQuery mobile: panel goes blank once opened and closed

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ios7, panel

i have just encountered a very strange problem. I am working with jQuery mobile and making the mobile version for a website. There is a listing page that has its own filters. The filters are in a panel, its slides out, you select the filter, it closes and filters the list. pretty basic. Now when the same app is accessed from an iOS 7 iphone, the first time you filter something it works fine. but if you open the filter again, its blank. but the filters are still where they should be and if you just tap at the place where you think a filter should be, they appear and filter the list as nothing is wrong. it remains like this after that.

This is the anchor i use to open the panel

```
<a id="friendsFilterAnchor" href="#friendsFilterPanel" data-mini="true" data-role="none" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-icon ui-icon-filter frindes-filter filter-ico" data-theme="a" title="Filter"></a>
```

and the panel looks something like this

```
<div data-role="panel" id="friendsFilterPanel" data-position-fixed="true"  data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">
        <ul id="friendsFilterList" data-role="listview"  data-theme="e" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li data-icon="ffTick" class="selected"><a href="javascript://" >All</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="javascript://">Pending</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="javascript://">Users</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
```

Anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: did you already have a solution? I'm currently facing the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the use of same ids on different pages. The previous page was also in the dom and it had the same id in it. use relative selectors, i.e get divs by searching on the same page, which is usually a good practice in javascript.

Comment: It seems like when I change data-display="push" to overlay or reveal this problem is fixed. Though I'd like to use the push display function instead of those 2.